# jQuery if/else statement for a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have 2 values that need to be stored in a database when checked, which is working fine if I do check both.

The problem is: if I have to add a 3rd input, and I only check the new "brand 3", the first 2 values already stored for "brand 1" and "brand 2" will be erased. But I need for those previous values to remain untouched and just write the new value for "brand 3"

```js
$(function() {

 set_checkbox_source_values();

 $('#at').submit(function(e) {
  set_checkbox_source_values();
 });
 
});


function set_checkbox_source_values() {
 $(".sub_checkbox").each(function(index){
  if ($(this).attr('checked')) 
  {
   $("input[data-brand='" + $(this).attr("data-brand") + "'][type='hidden']").val("ONBOT");
   
  } else {
   $("input[data-brand='" + $(this).attr("data-brand") + "'][type='hidden']").val('');
  }
 });
}
```

```html
<form method="POST" name="at" id="at">
      
      <input type="hidden" name="SOURCE_ORIG_brand1" value="" data-brand="1" />
      <input type="hidden" name="SOURCE_LAST_brand1" value="" data-brand="1" />
      <input type="hidden" name="SOURCE_ORIG_brand2" value="" data-brand="2" /> 
      <input type="hidden" name="SOURCE_LAST_brand2" value="" data-brand="2" /> 
      
      <input value="1617027553" data-brand="1" name="sub" type="checkbox" class="sub_checkbox" />
      <input value="1617027907" data-brand="2" name="sub" class="sub_checkbox" type="checkbox" />
   <input name="submit" value="sumbit" /> 
</form>
```

So, to clarify even more, this is what's happening. 
If I check the brand1 checkbox and leave the brand2 uncheck, this happens:

[Option 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnuIp.jpg)

But if I go back and check the brand2 checkbox and leave the brand1 uncheck, the value gets overriden and deletes the previous value leaving brand1 empty.

What I need my code to do is to post the SOURCE have to the empty field but to not override the previous value, so my ultimate goal is get this:

[Result needed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ID2T4.jpg)

Comment: It may help if you include your HTML and server-side code.

Comment: How does your server-side code handle empty or unposted values?

Comment: There are 2 other forms that also pass on values to an specific field on the database... so what I am trying to achieve here is: if the field is empty/blank then it pass the value otherwise it doesn't not affect the existing value on the field

Comment: I have included a sample HTML and a much more clear explanation of what Im trying to accomplish

Comment: The idea I'm proposing is to exclude unchanged variables from your database query, but there are a number of ways to do that. What server-side language are you using? Can we see how you process posted values and build the database query?

Comment: I am not sure about the first question. About the process im unable to provide any other information for security reason.

Is there a way to post a value if the field is empty but stop it from passing the value is the field is not empty?

Comment: Added more info...hope you can help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the answer depends partly on how your server-side code handles empty or undefined `$_POST` values. You could exclude blank values from your query, but then what if you want to set a value to a blank string?

Instead of clearing inputs' values, I suggest using the [`disabled` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-disabled) to prevent unchecked values from being posted. Then, in your server-side code, exclude unposted values from your query.

> ... a disabled control's value isn't submitted with the form.

Something like:

```
function set_checkbox_source_values() {
  $(".sub_checkbox").each(function(index) {
    $("input[data-brand='" + $(this).attr("data-brand") + "'][type='hidden']").prop('disabled', !this.checked);
  });
}
```

Here's an example using regular text inputs, just for demonstration.
You can use hidden inputs instead.

```js
jQuery('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function() {
  var code = jQuery(this).data('code');
  jQuery('input[type=text][data-code=' + code + ']').prop('disabled', !this.checked);
});
```

```css
div {
  margin: 0 0 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <input type="text" value="test1" data-code="tester1" disabled />
  <input type="checkbox" data-code="tester1" />
</div>
<div>
  <input type="text" value="test2" data-code="tester2" disabled />
  <input type="checkbox" data-code="tester2" />
</div>
<div>
  <input type="text" value="test3" data-code="tester3" disabled />
  <input type="checkbox" data-code="tester3" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Let me try this on and I will let you know if it works as soon as possible :)

Comment: I have included a sample HTML and a much more clear explanation of what Im trying to accomplish

Comment: Added more info...hope you can help :)